# How do I overlay a gradient (background) on top of a border?

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

I've got a heading with borders extending sideways (inspired by Chris Coyiers [example](http://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/)). I'm trying to fade the borders out by overlapping them with a gradient background. However, I'm not able to make it work, but I feel it should be possible somehow. To illustrate what effect I'm looking for:

*This is what I have now:*

[image: What I have now]

*And this is what I'm trying to achieve:*

[image: The effect I'm trying to achieve]

*The code I have now:*

HTML

```
<article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum etc.</p>
    <p class="fancy">
        <a href="#">read more</a>
    </p>
</article>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: red; /* Just to show the effect of the transparency, the final background will be white */
    font-size: 150%;
}

/* This is for the horizontal borders extending sideways from the heading */

 .fancy a {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Bitter', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

.fancy a:before, .fancy a:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: .1em;
    width: 50%;
    border-top: 1px dotted black;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
}

.fancy a:before {
    right: .5em;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

.fancy a:after {
    left: .5em;
    margin-right: -50%;
}

/* This is the gradient I want to display in front of the border. The body will have a white background, so it will look like the border is fading out */

 .fancy {
    /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    /* IE 10 */ 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}
```

*For easy fiddling the code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/QEdxe/3/*

Does anyone know how to do this? I've already tried with absolute positioning and z-index, but I can't get the gradient to overlap to dotted borders..

Comment: If at all possible, I would prefer to do this dynamically and in css. But I don't know if that can be done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this good for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/rcv5S/2/

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <p>Lorem ipsum etc.</p>
    <a class="fancy" href="#">
        <span>read more</span>
    </a>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: white; /* Just to show the effect of the transparency, the final background will be white */
    font-size: 150%;
}

/* This is for the horizontal borders extending sideways from the heading */

a.fancy {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'Bitter', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

a.fancy > span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    padding: 0 .5em;
}

a.fancy:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: black;
}

a.fancy:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    /* Firefox 3.6+ */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    /* IE 10 */ 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}
```

Comment: It is, that's absolutely perfect. You even did it with less elements than I had (without the `<p>`), which is even better :). Thank you!